# Angular RxJS: event emitted twice

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've coded two observables:

One for cathing form submit events:

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="search()">
   ...
</form>
```

And `search()` is reached and emits:

```
private search(): void {
    this.searchClickSubject.next();
}
```

In component constructor:

```
private searchClickSubject:Subject<void>;
private searchClick$:Observable<any>;

constructor() {
    this.searchClickSubject = new Subject<void>();
    this.searchClick$ = this.searchClickSubject.asObservable();
}
```

As you can see I create an `Observable` from subject `searchClickSubject` using `searchClickSubject.asObservable` method on `searchClick$`.

From now on, I'm using this `searchClick$` Observable in order to catch `submit form`.

After that, I'm creating another Observable:

```
    this.searchQuery$ = this.searchClick$.pipe(
        map(() => <Query>{
            offset: 0,
            limit: 10
        })
    );
```

So, each time a `Query` is emitted I make requestm using custom pipeable functions:

```
    this.metrics$ = this.searchQuery$
        .pipe(
          pageLoading(),
          makeRequest(),
          loadedPage()
        );
```

This is my `ngOnInit()`:

```
public ngOnInit() {            
    // Grab search button click event
    this.searchQuery$ = this.searchClick$.pipe(
        map(() => <Query>{
            offset: 0,
            limit: 10
        })
    );

    this.metrics$ = this.searchQuery$
        .pipe(
          //...
        );
}
```

However, request is launched twice.

I create subscriptions using `async` pipeline:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="!(metrics$ | async)" style="margin: 1.54em;">

<div *ngIf="metrics$ | async; let metric;"...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you subscribe to `metrics$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You subscribe to the observable `metrics$` two times. Here is what happens:

1. You subscribe by using `*ngIf="!(metrics$ | async)"`.
2. When you click search, it immediately fires the observable, and everything you chained on it, including your request.
3. You subscribe using `*ngIf="metrics$ | async; let metric;"`.
4. Step 2 happens again, separately.

Use the `share()` operator in `metrics$` to prevent remaking the request on a new subscription. If you want to have a deeper understanding of this topic, check out this [great article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635).

Comment: Why are you telling I'm using a `BehaviorSubject`? As far I've been able to figure out I'm using a `Subject<void>` as a initial source in order to catch form submits... By other hand... What about `ReplaySubject`? I think it's not a good idea to share and http request...

Comment: So, I mean, `share()` operator is a good work-around, but I think it smells as such an a "work-around". According to ot and cold issues: first observable is hot (form submits), then after `switchMap` it turns to a cold observable, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's a workaround in this case. You have a component, and in that component, you want to _share_ the same observable between two subscriptions. You are right, you don't use _BehaviorSubject_, my bad, sorry. The situation is the same though.

Answer (score 2):

You have subscribed to `metrics$` two times, instead of this you can use `as` syntax, as below

```
<div *ngIf="metrics$ | async as metric; else loading">
   <!-- Statements when metrics data found  -->
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
   <!-- Loading stuff...  -->
  <div class="row" style="margin: 1.54em;">
</ng-template>
```

Refer [Handling observables with NgIf & Async Pipe](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe) for more details.